# How can I fake a rusticated block appearance?

Tags: concrete, masonry

I am going to be installing rusticated block to match my existing house, the type of stone sold by https://classicrockfaceblock.com and others.  However, there is one, small face of the block that is not rusticated: a 4" x 8" face on the opposing end of an L corner piece.

This is a pretty small area, and I think free-handing the rustication ought to be good enough, it will be difficult to notice, but I know if it were entirely flat it would be noticeable.

I read that mortar is used as a 'glue' between blocks.  The fake-rustication will not be gluing anything together, it will just be additional stuff slapped onto the outside of a block and it needs to stay there without falling.  What is the best way to accomplish this?  Can I use concrete on the block after it is installed (i.e. gravity won't pull it off)?  Or maybe I should use concrete on the block before it is installed (so I can turn it on its side and gravity won't affect it while it dries)?

**Edit**: To better explain what I am trying to accomplish, I've added a sketch - all blocks are 8" high.  I need to add a 4" thick extension to the wall for columns. (Here pictured at a corner - there is also one not on a corner, but that one is easy to accomplish with the blocks available.)

The veneer available at that site does not come in 4" dimensions, I would need one that is 4" x 8" (where 8" is the height).  It is that side of the L block that is flat (from the manufacturer) that I want to fake the rustication on.

(It also occurs to me that there are several blocks were I need rustication on only *part* of the block (e.g. the first 4" or first 12"...)

[image: Image showing block layout]

Comment: Why don't you use one of the veneers?

Comment: Why would the unfinished face be visible?  The blocks are designed so all the visible faces are finished. How are you using that L block?  And, even if you have a good answer to this, why indeed don't you just use the veneers from the same vendor?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the website you linked, there are blocks produced that have multiple sides textured with the rusticated finish as well as a selection of veneers available.

[image: rusticated block]

You could likely work directly with the supplier to figure out how many of the specialized blocks you need to include for the corners or whatnot and purchase an appropriate number of multi-faced blocks for those locations. I'm sure their customer service department can help you with this.

In the event that they can't provide a product variant to help you, I think you could mix up a batch of mortar or cement and try to reproduce the rustication effect by applying it to the exposed surface of the block. You may have to experiment a little to get the viscosity and texture just right but it shouldn't be too difficult. Again, the manufacturer's customer service might be helpful to you if you feel that you need to pursue this course.